# Listing active radio buttons within tab widget or layout?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt

I have a plugin widget with some tabs, and within the tabs a layout of radio buttons as shown below:

[image]

I would like to capture the list of active radio buttons within each tab like so:
[image]

Is there an easy way to do this dynamically  for each tab instead of programatically capturing the state of each radio button?

here is the structure of the UI in QT designer if it helps:
[image]

Comment: you can find QRadioButton object in each tab `self.mytab.findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton)` and iterate for get if each radio button is checked or not

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which allows to parse the Tabs in a TabWidget and make a dictionnary of all the Radio buttons inside them:

```py
# make a dictionary for each tab and the list of radio buttons in each one
self.dockwidget = Filtres_standards_PDSDockWidget()
TabWidget = self.dockwidget.FilterTabs.children()            
StackedWidgets = [SWidget for SWidget in  TabWidget if isinstance(SWidget,qw.QStackedWidget)][0]
TabsList = [Tab for Tab in StackedWidgets.children() if isinstance(Tab,qw.QWidget)]                
RadioButtonsLists={Tab.objectName() : [RadioButtons for RadioButtons in Tab.children() if isinstance(RadioButtons, qw.QRadioButton)] for Tab in TabsList}
```

then a fuction that checks which RButtons are checked to build a query:

```py
#A function to check whithin each tab the list of checked radiobuttons and building a query from it   
def querybuilder(RadioButtonsLists):
    QueryText=''
    for RadioButtonsList in RadioButtonsLists:
        checkedOnRb = ''
        RBListlen = []
        for RadioButton in RadioButtonsLists[RadioButtonsList]:
            if RadioButton.isChecked():
                RBListlen.append(1)
                if len(checkedOnRb)==0:
                    checkedOnRb = RadioButton.text()
                else:
                    checkedOnRb += ", " + RadioButton.text()
        if len(RBListlen)>0:
            if len(QueryText)==0:
                QueryText = RadioButtonsList + ' in (' + str(checkedOnRb) + ')'
            else:
                QueryText += ' and ' + RadioButtonsList + ' in (' + str(checkedOnRb) + ')'
    return QueryText

def printquery(RadioButtonsLists):
    self.dockwidget.label.setText(str(querybuilder(RadioButtonsLists)))
```

the result:

[image]